# python not taking input after subprocess is called with subprocess.popen

Tags: python, subprocess

Hello everyone im fairly new to python and this is my first language im learning so far. Im making a menu using a while true loop that takes input to select whichever flashing method a person needs to use and after calling whatever file using subprocess.popen or subprocess.call and it finishes it goes back into the menu loop but does not respond to any input at all.

```
import sys
import time
import subprocess


#!/bin/bash
sys.path.append

menu = True
def mainMenu():
    while menu:
        print("""
        @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
        @ Utilities Menu @
        @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
    
    1. Tray Flasher
    2. ESP Burner
    3. Quit
    """)

      choice = (input('Select a utility: '))
      if choice == '1':
          trayFlasher()
        
      elif choice == '2':
          espBurner()
       

      elif choice == '3':
          print('Goodbye!')
        


def trayFlasher():
   print('Have Fun!')
   time.sleep(1)
   subprocess.call(["<path to file>"])
    

def espBurner():
   print('Burn Baby Burn...')
   time.sleep(1)
   subprocess.Popen(['<path to file>'])
```

sorry if my code is not so good or efficient, currently still learning. TIA!

Comment: Only the `print()` statement is in your `while` loop. Check the indention, rest of the function is outside of the loop

Comment: @jordanm woops sorry code got a little jacked up when i copied it into here, fixed it to represent how it actually is in my IDE